# Correct MySQL Syntax for returning multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am wanting to query a database and pull retrieve information from a number of rows but i am unsure of the `MySQL` Syntax. Something like this;

```
SELECT LastName FROM Users WHERE ID = 1 AND ID = 2 AND ID = 3
```

So i am wanting to receive back

Smith, Doe, and Doe

```
Users
ID    FirstName    LastName    
1     John         Smith
2     Joe          Doe
3     Jane         Doe
More data etc etc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A cleaner approach:

```
SELECT LastName FROM Users WHERE ID IN(1, 2, 3);
```

This is basically the same thing as writing:

```
SELECT LastName FROM Users WHERE ID = 1 OR ID = 2 OR ID = 3;
```

Your query will not return any rows, simply because you're using:

```
ID = 1 AND ID = 2 AND ID = 3
```

A table row can not have an ID of 1 ***AND*** an ID of 2. Hence the reason we use OR.